# Global if condition to local if condition

Tags: jquery

Below is a script for counting slides number like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slidesLength = $('#main-work-slider .carousel-inner .item').length,
    replaceSlidesLength = $('.slides-counter .slides-length').html('/ ' + slidesLength),
    addSlides = 1,
    slideNumber = $('.slides-number'),
    ourWorkNext = $('.our-work-controls .right'),
    ourWorkPrev = $('.our-work-controls .left');
    ourWorkNext.click(function(){
        slideNumber.html((addSlides += 1));

        /* here the if condition which is working fine with next button but
           it effects also on the prev button (global if condition) when i reach
           the boundry and go prev it gives me '-1' because the if condition has
           a global closure and i want to know how can i make it local to its
           function */

        if(addSlides >= slidesLength){

            addSlides = 0;
        }
    });

    ourWorkPrev.click(function(){
        slideNumber.html((addSlides -= 1));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably check the value of addSlides before setting it and set it to the length of your slides accordingly if the value goes below zero.

```
ourWorkPrev.click(function(){
    addSlides -= 1;
    if(addSlides<0)addSlides = slidesLength;
    slideNumber.html(addSlides);
});
```

Comment: ok i have another question on the same code but new lines was added the issue is when i count i want to do like a filteriton (fade in/out) to some data and i did it ok with the nextbtn and prevbtn but they don't loop when i start over from slide#1 or start by clicking the prevbtn to start with last slide it keep counting but not fade in / out data

Comment: From looking at your code posted below you should probably do the calculation of your "addSlides"-variable before starting the fadeIn/Out.

Comment: your fiddle is actually very good and is looping well but it counts from 0 when i customize on the code it results counting but not goning to the last count which in my case 3 please advice ... thank you

Comment: thank you man but i have a question is is possible to work in fiddle very well but copy it to my structure not working very well ?